# React Accordion and React Leaflet render conflict

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion, react-leaflet

I have a project that needs to render a React Accordion on the top div and a React Leaflet at the bottom. The code looks something like this.

```
return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="weather-container">
            <Search onSearchChange={handleOnSearchChange}/>
            {forecast && <Forecast data={forecast} />}
        </div>
        <div className="map-container">
            {coordinates && <OSM data={coordinates} />}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
```

The Forecast component is the accordion, and the OSM component is the Leaflet.
However, the Leaflet component could not render at all. I am not sure if React Accordion is interfering with it. I then commented the Leaflet's style sheet.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  MapContainer,
  TileLayer,
  useMap
} from 'react-leaflet'

//import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css' // this line is important

const OSM = ({data}) => {

  const ResizeMap = () => {
    const map = useMap();
    map._onResize();
    return null;
  };

  let center = [parseFloat(data[0]), parseFloat(data[1])]

  return (
    <div id="map">
        <MapContainer className="leaflet-container" center={center} zoom={3} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
            <ResizeMap/>
            <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
        </MapContainer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default OSM
```

And I got some really strange render.

Both the Accordion and Leaflet takes the whole page to render, but I want each to take up half the space.

[image]

Comment: Could you share the css styles you use for `#map`and `map-container`.
I think that you need to set a fixed hight on the wrapping div e.g. `500px`or `50vh. Percentages will not work for what I know

Comment: .weather-container{
  max-width: 1089px;
  margin: 20px auto;

}

.map-container{
  align-items: center;
}

Comment: Okay try to set a height in the OSM component, to just see if that is the issue e.g.  `<div id="map" style={{height: "500px"}} >`